# Resizing images and keep them in original position with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, image

I've been struggling the whole day trying to figure our how to resize image and compute proportions. I've mostly failed!

To describe my problem, sorry! But I can't find any words... So here's this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/TkPX5/

As you can see there's an image with a couch and a sheep (if you don't: try resizing the browser window).

Now, keep resizing your browser window: you should see both the sheep and the couch get resized. I just want the damn sheep to stay on the couch, in a **fixed position**, like if it was hardcoded in the couch image. No matter the window dimension, the sheep must stay on the couch.

No, I cannot use Photoshop and paste the sheep over it.

In the final project, instead of the couch I will have an interface and the sheep will be a knob or a button.

If you want to try yourself, scroll the javascript until you get to the bottom where you'll see a "TODO" comment.

There are two lines of code which change the sheep position: every other parameter you need to compute those are already in the code above (or at least I hope so!). I just miss the formula.

I've been able to resize the sheep dynamically and proportional to the couch: how can I do the same with its position? I've tried !EVERYTHING! but nothings seems to work :'(

Thank you very much in advance!

edit: seems like the fiddle link was wrong. Fixed!

Comment: sorry guys! the link was wrong!

Comment: I think you meant to link: http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/TkPX5/3/

Comment: yep, but in that link there's an unused line of code which may confuse someone. I've delete it in the link in the original question :) Mabye you have to reload the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting `x` and `y` to a fixed value, you need to adjust them relative to the new height and width of the the image.

```
x = masterX + (50 * w / imm1.width);
y = masterY + (235 * h / imm1.height);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TkPX5/12/

Comment: you, sir, will be my hero and saver! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks man!